# Why can't I grab an element on a webpage with selenium in python? Tried by id, xpath, full xpath

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, autofill, inspect-element

I'm trying to write a script that will auto-fill an online form with python and selenium, but I'm having trouble grabbing an element from the html code.

This is my starting code. Everything works until I try to identify the element. The element's id changes for every new instance of the website, so I'm trying a workaround which I believe grabs the correct id for each instance:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import requests
web = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://lincdoc.ou.edu/lincdoc/doc/run/ouathletics/OU_AdvisingForm2#ldTimeoutUri'
web.get(url)
html_text = requests.get(url).text
instance_id_index = html_text.index("<div id=")
instance_id = html_text[instance_id_index+9] + html_text[instance_id_index+10] + html_text[instance_id_index+11] + html_text[instance_id_index+12] 
student_id = "ID NUMBER"
student_id_box_id = instance_id + "q4"
```

I've tried the following, which all come back with a no such element exception:

(1) tried and failed to grab student id textbox element by id

```
web.find_element(By.ID, student_id_box_id).send_keys(student_id)
```

(2) tried and failed to grab student id textbox element by xpath

```
student_id_box_xpath = '//*[@id="' + instance_id + 'q4"]'
web.find_element(By.XPATH, student_id_box_xpath).send_keys(student_id)
```

(3) tried and failed to grab student id textbox element by full xpath

```
student_id_box_xpath = '//*[@id="' + instance_id + 'q4"]'
student_id_box_full_xpath = student_id_box_xpath + '/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[3]/table/tbody[2]/tr[1]/td[3]/div/input'
web.find_element(By.XPATH, student_id_box_full_xpath).send_keys(student_id)
```

Can anyone shed some light on this? I'm very very new to programming and python and it took awhile for me to get even this far. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use an [attribute = value css selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) with $ ends with operator to specify the input element with id ending with q4

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 

web = webdriver.Chrome()
web.get('https://lincdoc.ou.edu/lincdoc/doc/run/ouathletics/OU_AdvisingForm2#ldTimeoutUri')
student_id_field = WebDriverWait(web, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id$=q4]")))
student_id_field.send_keys("some id goes here")
```

Comment: Thank you SO SO MUCH! It worked perfectly!! I didn't know about the $ ends with operator, so thank you for showing me that. It's much less complicated than the way I tried to get the instance id. And I didn't know about the CSS Selector option, so thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

the id of this page is dynamic, it is better to use table, row as anchor element, I wrote one sample to solve this issue, you can view the full code from [here](https://github.com/automation9417/automation-samples/tree/main/FillFormSample)

sample as the following:

```
from clicknium import clicknium as cc, locator, ui

tab = cc.chrome.open("https://lincdoc.ou.edu/lincdoc/doc/run/ouathletics/OU_AdvisingForm2#ldTimeoutUri")
tab.find_element(locator.chrome.lincdoc.text_advising_unit).set_text("Athletics-OMS 256/(405) 325-8373")
tab.find_element(locator.chrome.lincdoc.text_advising_name).set_text("AJ Tierney__ajtierney@ou.edu")

tab.find_element(locator.chrome.lincdoc.text_student_id).set_text("student1")
tab.find_element(locator.chrome.lincdoc.text_first_name).set_text("tom")
tab.find_element(locator.chrome.lincdoc.text_last_name).set_text("jack")
tab.find_element(locator.chrome.lincdoc.text_phone_number).set_text("12345")
tab.find_element(locator.chrome.lincdoc.text_ou_email).set_text("test@lincdoc.ou.edu")
tab.find_element(locator.chrome.lincdoc.text_student_id).set_text("Junior")

tab.find_element(locator.chrome.lincdoc.checkbox_topic, {'topic':'Academic Contract'}).set_checkbox()

print('done')
```